# Include JS library using vueJS laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I'm using vue-cli with webpack and Laravel.
Loading js files like jQuery from cdn in my app.blade.php is working but i don't want to include my files from cdns...

using

```
require('@/js/assets/jquery.js');
```

in app.js is not working. When a look at the complied app.js in my browser it seems that jQUery is imported but i have an error saying "$ is undefined".

This is the same for every js  /css files i'm trying to add in my vue app.

app.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <title>MTM</title>
        <link href=" {{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="app">
        <app></app>
   </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js','.vue'],
        alias:{
            '@': __dirname + '/resources'
        }
    }
})
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

app.js

```
require('@/css/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.css');
require('@/js/assets/jQuery.js');
require('@/js/assets/semantic.js');
require('@/js/assets/tablesort.js');
```

Comment: Did you place these requirements before any other code?

Comment: No i have some imports before but placing them first is not solving the probleme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to specify webpack to load jQuery and there are some ways to do using

inside `webpack.config.js`

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            })
        ]
    };
});
```

alongside `npm install jquery` or `yarn add jquery`

and in your `app.js` file add

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Where do i need to put this ? thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 2):

You just import the module itself but you need to assign jQuery to a variable if you want to use it with `$` within your app.js module.

Eg. in your app.js:

```
var $ = require('@/js/assets/jQuery.js');
```

If you want to use jQuery globally you have to assign it to a global variable like this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('@/js/assets/jQuery.js');
```

See the npm [package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) for more information about the usage.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it doesn't solve the probleme, i totally don't understand why it change nothing using this method...

Comment: See my edit on how to assign jQuery to a global variable, that can be used throughout your entire application and not just within your app.js module.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Laravel, Vue, and JQuery.  For me, the fix was installing JQuery with `npm install jquery`, and then editing the webpack.mix.js file to copy it to my public js folders like so...

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js')
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <title>MTM</title>
        <link href=" {{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="app">
        <app></app>
   </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using var $ = require('@/js/assets/jQuery.js'); doesn't change anything..

This my full app.js file :

```
import './bootstrap'
import Vue from 'vue'
import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Routes from '@/js/routes.js'
import App from '@/js/views/App'

var $ = require('@/js/assets/jQuery.js');

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(vueResource);
Vue.prototype.$env_uri = '';

export const notificationBus = new Vue();
export const deleteModalBus = new Vue();
export const appModalBus = new Vue();
export const loaderBus = new Vue();

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    router: Routes,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

export default app;
```

the error a get :

```
__webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/EditFdr.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& http://api.mtm/js/app.js:2957 __webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 ./resources/js/views/EditFdr.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& http://api.mtm/js/app.js:50191 __webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 vue http://api.mtm/js/app.js:50153 __webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 js http://api.mtm/js/app.js:49748 __webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 js http://api.mtm/js/app.js:43038 __webpack_require__ http://api.mtm/js/app.js:20 0 http://api.mtm/js/app.js:50560 __webpack_require__
```